# How to write a URL rewrite rule in g-wan?

Tags: web-server, rewrite, g-wan

I want URLs with the host foobar.com to be rewritten to www.foobar.com. How can I do this with g-wan?

Answer (score 3):

There's a G-WAN [rewrite example here](http://gwan.com/developers#handler) (look at the second handler source code, the first handler example illustrates FLV pseudo-streaming).

Comment: Here is a more complete G-WAN rewrite example with debugging tips: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479044/g-wan-url-rewrite-for-home-page-not-working/13496479#13496479

Answer (score 1):

You can Use a virtual host, or even an alias, see the [G-WAN FAQs](http://gwan.com/faq#listener).

For more elaborate rewrites, you can use a handler, some examples are provided in the download archive.